# How to include cross domain javascript libraries in IE?

Tags: jquery, django, internet-explorer, heroku, cross-domain

I have my site running on Heroku and the static assets are on AWS S3. So all includes come via 's3.amazonaws.com' Now this works perfectly fine across chrome and firefox but not on IE. It shows a permission denied error while trying to load the js files.

I read [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) but am still not clear which of those is the best cross-browser solution.

Comment: Same-origin policy does not apply for loading of static assets in things like `<script>`, `<img>`, etc.  Are you sure the problem isn't a permissions problem on S3 (i.e. S3 isn't configured to make those files publicly available)?

Comment: Well I have put very liberal policies on S3. But even if it is a S3 issue, how can I explain that it works on chrome, firefox but not IE?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you.  I just know that same-origin policy is not the problem.  Look at the source for this stackoverflow page as an example.  It loads scripts from a variety of domains.  It works fine in IE.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: Yup. I was pretty sure it works the way you described it but IE surprised me and I felt I was missing something. It actually works on IE with this setting - On IE7, IE8, and IE9 just go to Settings->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level and change security settings under "Miscellaneous" set "Access data sources across domains" to Enable.